# home button/long press breaks activity stack

Tags: android

I have A,B activities..

A is the launcher activity.

User goes from A -> B

User presses home button -> Launches browser -> long press on home button -> selects my application -> now B is on stack and hitting back button does not take him from B -> A.

A is singleInstance activity.

I want A activity to be accessible from anywhere with help of back button.

Is there a simple way OR do I have to catch back button event and start A activity.

And since A is single instance it will be fetched from instance which is already there on stack/dvm.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It woked after doing following

1. Remove singleinstance launchmode from A
2. Whenever starting activity A make sure you have FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP launchmode. If you dont do this there will be long chain of activities after some time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to catch the back button and call A if you want to start A every time the user presses back.

But make sure you have a good reason to so the same as this breaks the regular flow of the app and unless handled correctly one might create an looped/screwed ( :-) ) activity stack.

It would be better if you launch Activity A from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use **singleInstance** in activity unless you know what you're doing.
**singleInstance** creates new Task and causes unintentionall behavior in your solution.

Read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html). It will give you more information how to handle Tasks and Back Stacks.

Or write more what you want to implement.

Comment: If you seen latest facebook app...there home page includes all icons...So it acts as gateway to all other pages...I want exactly like that...

Comment: Why can't you do it with standard launchMode?